# C++ no matching function for call to 'strlcpy'

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code.

```
void CInputMain::GetWhisperDetails(LPCHARACTER ch, const char * c_pData)
{
    TPacketCGGetWhisperDetails* p = (TPacketCGGetWhisperDetails *) c_pData;

    if (!*p->szName)
        return;

    TPacketGCGetWhisperDetails p2;
    p2.header = HEADER_GC_WHISPER_DETAILS;
    strlcpy(p2.szName, p->szName, sizeof(p2.szName));

    LPCHARACTER pkChr = CHARACTER_MANAGER::instance().FindPC(p->szName);
    if (pkChr && pkChr->IsPC())
    {
        p2.bOnline = 1;
        strlcpy(p2.szLanguage, pkChr->GetLanguage(), sizeof(p2.szLanguage));
        strlcpy(p2.bEmpire, pkChr->GetEmpire(), sizeof(p2.bEmpire));
    }
    else
    {
        p2.bOnline = 0;
        strlcpy(p2.szLanguage, "en", sizeof(p2.szLanguage));
        strlcpy(p2.bEmpire, 1, sizeof(p2.bEmpire));
    }
    ch->GetDesc()->Packet(&p2, sizeof(p2));
}
```

The error is:

```
strlcpy(p2.szLanguage, pkChr->GetLanguage(), sizeof(p2.szLanguage));

strlcpy(p2.bEmpire, pkChr->GetEmpire(), sizeof(p2.bEmpire));

 no matching function for call to 'strlcpy'
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: There's no such function as `strlcpy`. I guess you meant `strncpy`?

Comment: `strlcpy` is not a standard C++ function.

Comment: According to the man page, strlcpy is defined in `bsd/string.h`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you already take the [tour] and learn [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please post a [mre] of your problem and include the complete error message (usually the compiler also lists one or more candidates if there is no matching function, which might give a clue of the problem).

Comment: NB: A [search for this error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22no+matching+function+for+call%22) on Stack Overflow yields already 2217 results. Are you sure this question is not already answered?